# Am I missing something in my urlpatterns?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to create a simple update function for my recipes, and i'm having some trouble with my urlpatterns.

This is my desired url path, but I keep getting an 404 (Page not found) error.

```
path('update-recipe/<slug:recipe_slug>/', views.update_recipe, name='update_recipe'),
```

[image]

my views.py file is like this.

```
def update_recipe(request, recipe_slug):

    form = RecipeForm()


    return render(request, 'recipes/update_recipe.html', {'form': form})
```

if i change my urlpattern to the following, everything seems to work correctly. But that isnt what I'm trying to achieve.

```
path('<slug:recipe_slug>/', views.update_recipe, name='update_recipe'),
```

The output with the above url.
[image]

I dont seem to understand what I'm doing wrong, I've tried following videos to the dot as well, but i get the same result.

Comment: try to put the `path('update-recipe/<slug:recipe_slug>/'` before `path('<slug:recipe_slug>/<slug:recipe_slug>/'`

Comment: @BrownBear I'm sorry, i didnt get what you meant. I've  tried `path('<slug:recipe_slug>/update-recipe/'`, still doesnt work

Comment: I mean in your `urls.py` file put the line with code `update-recipe...` before line with code `slug/slug`. Is it enough clear?

Comment: @BrownBear Holy Shit! That worked!! Thank You, Do you mind telling me why it works like that?

Comment: cause, no magic - django build the sequence of the urls, and the pattern `slug/slug/` eat the pattern `update-recipe/slug`. More details you can find [how-django-processes-a-request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)